# Do we need to protect digital outputs?

Tags: protection, circuit-protection

I studied some documents which say that we need to protect digital inputs that come from some devices like NIDAQ in relation to ESD, short circuit or even overvoltage. But what about digital outputs? Some times we need to provide some digital signals to our circuit for turning on or off some switches, for example. Do we have to do something to protect the digital output?

Comment: If digital output goes outside of the device - it's better to protect it in any available way (most simple - BJT with ESD protection for the collector, most hardcore - with galvanic isolation). When you have any abnormal situation (short circuit for example) and output blows - repair procedure for discrete BJT is much more simple and cheap than for MCU

Comment: @Looongcat: yeah, because in the average consumer equipment we repair so much these days...

Comment: @loongcat and @ plasmaHH:  someone suggested me use a zener diode parallel to output pin and also mentioned to use a resistor in seri with zener diode in shuch way that whole resistor seri connected to zener diode are parallel to digital output (0-5v). but i couldnt get the point. i wonder if you could explain or help me about the concept. thats tru?

Comment: @Diana just read about how zener diode works. It's the most simple overvoltage protection.

Comment: @PlasmaHH the average consumer (at least in industrial automation) is lazy enough to ignore manuals. He takes the device, mounts it, turns it on and then frustrates why it got broken and blames the manufacturer :)

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zxRxp.jpg                                                
it is the same concept? because some circuits are using output form between resistor and zener diode.

Comment: @Looongcat - and the consumer who blames the manufacturer in such a case has a point

Comment: @ScottSeidman okay, when your customer will ignore all NEC and yours recommendations (the most simple case - will install 10kW inverter on one shelf with control logic, or mount power cables with signal ones) and will blame you because "it don't works!" - we'll talk again :) Any customer wants to buy needed device which will survive in any possible and impossible cases, but often it's impossible or just too expensive.

Comment: @Diana you don't need the resistor, just zener diode

Comment: @loongcat: sorry for asking again. this zener is for reulating the voltage? let imagin the output digital voltage is 5. in this case the what is the voltage of zener diode? 5.6 or something like that?

Comment: @Looongcat  -  when a consumer buys a piece of electronics off the shelf, generally the consumer doesn't stop to read a manual or instruction page, and expects to look at the device and understand how it works.  Most certainly, there should be ZERO failure modes in which the consumer can trash the device by plugging something in wrong.  I suggest that designers and manufacturers who can design to those specs are more successful than those who do not.  I highly recommend reading some of John Norman's books.

Comment: @ScottSeidman any design is possible, it's just a question of expensiveness. And thanks for the book! :)

Comment: @Diana yup, 5.6V should be fine

Comment: It would be *much* easier to provide a god answer if you were specific about the application and outputs being driven. Without specific applications it is hard to do anything mre useful than a 'shopping list' of suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'd better protect output from these situations:

1. with a small resistor in series to protect from drawing over-current in a short circuit or failure.
2. with an optocoupler to separate high power from MCU digital or low voltage if frequency allow. Optocouplers have low frequency.
3. with multi stages transistors, MOSFETs or special drivers (depending on situation).